# Displaying binary images on JSP page

Tags: jsp, postgresql, jakarta-ee, arrays

So here is the problem. I have images stored in PostgreSQL in bytea (byte array) type. Also I have a home JSP page, which has to display all photos from db. Please, point me to the solution or some ways to achieve this requirement.
With best regards.
Nazar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [img src="url"] tag to reference your images from the database and show on the site.

```
var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: "image/jpg"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob, { oneTimeOnly: true });
```

Blob is actually supported directly by URL.createObjectURL. The only catch is that you have to specify a mime format to identify the buffer format, which in my case is possible.

So after you get the url use the image tag. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Well, actually I can't just put an URL in img tag. Photos are stored in binary code, there are no URL's available.